# Spring Boot Stop Gracefuly From @Scheduled Method

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I am trying to stop a Spring Boot application based on a database value like this:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000)
public void checkShutdown() {

    boolean shouldShutdown = readFromDatabase();

    if (shouldShutdown) {
        log.info("Shutdown requested.");
        SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext, () -> 0);
        return;
    }
}
```

When the app is exiting, it throws a nasty exception, because the Hikari data source is interrupted and not allowed to close gracefully. Here is the exception:

```
2023-05-13T10:24:47.924-03:00  INFO 248948 --- [   scheduling-1] c.e.d.example.service.ShutdownService   : Shutdown requested.
2023-05-13T10:24:47.934-03:00  WARN 248948 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Interrupted while waiting for executor 'taskScheduler' to terminate
2023-05-13T10:24:47.939-03:00  INFO 248948 --- [   scheduling-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-05-13T10:24:47.944-03:00  INFO 248948 --- [   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-05-13T10:24:47.949-03:00  WARN 248948 --- [   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Interrupted during closing

java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1660) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1464) ~[na:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.shutdown(HikariPool.java:243) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.close(HikariDataSource.java:351) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:222) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:587) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:559) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1182) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1084) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1053) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1003) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.close(SpringApplication.java:1397) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.java:1350) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at com.example.service.ShutdownService.checkShutdown(ShutdownService.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I have tried setting the following properties, but it made no difference:

```yaml
spring:
  task:
    execution:
      shutdown:
        await-termination: true
        await-termination-period: 15s
    scheduling:
      shutdown:
        await-termination: true
        await-termination-period: 15s
```

I also tried calling `applicationContext.close()` instead of `SpringApplication.exit`, but it also made no difference.

Comment: You could try using a try catch block to catch the exception. I wonder also if using Spring Boot’s Actuator to create a custom health check could be useful in your case, which you could set up to return Health.down()… when the shouldShutdown is true and also when the db connection fails. It looks like something sort of similar might be described [here](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-health-check/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `HikariDataSource.close()` has done the trick:

```java
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000)
public void checkShutdown() {

    boolean shouldShutdown = readFromDatabase();

    if (shouldShutdown) {
        log.info("Shutdown requested.");
        hikariDataSource.close();
        SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext, () -> 0);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do like this on a Service/Component bean, depending on your requirements:

```
@PreDestroy
public void close() {
    // application is closed
}
```